# Pandas. Dataframe. sns.heatmap - Отрисовка результата

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ребята, выручайте. Несколько дней голову ломаю, не могу решить проблему.В питоне я новичок.
Код пишу в Notebook Jupyter

Вообщем вот сама задача:

Task 5:

1. Разбейте расходы (отрицательные значения сумм) на 5 бакетов amount_bucket равного объёма (с помощью pd.qcut), разбив все траты на категории 'Very High', 'High', 'Middle', 'Low', 'Very Low'. (*)
2. Оставшиеся неотрицательные траты отнесите к категории 'Income'. (воспользуйтесь функцией .cat.add_categories('Income') для того, чтобы добавить новую категорию 'Income' к категориям 'Very High', 'High', 'Middle', 'Low', 'Very Low', а затем заполните пустые значения новой категорией).
3. Из поля tr_datetime выделите час tr_hour, в который произошла транзакция, как первые 2 цифры до ":". (**)
4. После этого постройте сводную таблицу, значениями в которой является пол gender, индексы - tr_hour, столбцы - amount_bucket.
5. Отрисуйте полученные результаты, передав их в функцию plot_pivot_table, расположенную ниже.

Пояснения:
(*) Обратите внимание, что в категории Very High Должны оказаться максимальные по модулю отрицательные транзакции.
(**) Например, для строки "0 10:23:26" час будет равен 10, а для строки "6 07:08:31"- 07. Можно воспользоваться функциями str.split() или str.find() и функцией .apply(lambda x: x[])

Вот то,что я написал:

```
    #Изначально имеется csv таблица с кучей записей, ее читаю во frame. Дальше все по заданию
 
otric = frame[frame.amount<0].amount
 
frame['amount_bucket'] = pd.qcut(otric,5,labels=['Very High','High','Middle','Low','Very Low'])
frame['amount_bucket'] = frame['amount_bucket'].cat.add_categories('Income').fillna('Income') 
 
hours = frame['tr_datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[1].split(':')[0])
amount_bucket = frame['amount_bucket']
amount_bucket = np.array(amount_bucket.values)
gender = frame['gender']
 
 
data = {'gender' : gender.values,
        'amount_bucket' : amount_bucket}
 
frameNew = pd.DataFrame(data,index=hours.values,columns=['gender','amount_bucket'])
frameNew .gender = frameNew .gender.astype(float)
frameNew .index = frameNew .index.astype(float)
 
 
frameNew = frameNew [(frameNew .gender==1.0) | (frameNew .gender==0.0)]
 
 
def plot_pivot_table(pivot_table):
    plt.figure(figsize=(9, 11))
    sns.heatmap(pivot_table, cmap="YlGnBu", annot=True, 
                fmt='.3g', annot_kws={"size": 14, "fontsize": 14})
    plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
    plt.yticks(rotation=0, fontsize=15)
    plt.xlabel('Bucket', size=18)
    plt.ylabel('Hour', fontsize=18)
    plt.title('Gender analysis per bucket and hour', fontsize=20)
    plt.show()
 
plot_pivot_table(frameNew)
```

В конце выбивает ошибку : 'TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

В инете пишут,что из-за того,что один из столбцов - не число. И действительно,если убрать 'amount_bucket' отсюда frameNew = pd.DataFrame(data,index=hours.values,columns=['gender','amount_bucket']) ,то вроде какой-то график отображается, но мне по заданию этот столбец необходим. Я без понятия что делать, вроде все по заданию сделал - но не работает.

Comment: А что говорит `frameNew.isna().sum()`, например?

Comment: Да, и зачем вы `gender` и `index` переводите в `float`, я что-то не уловил?

Comment: Да, и ещё посмотреть бы `frame.shape` до всех этих манипуляций и `frameNew.shape` после всего этого, а то меня терзают смутные сомнения. Ну и `frameNew.head()` хотя бы и `frameNew.info()` до кучи.

Comment: @CrazyElf вот что выдает frameNew.isna().sum() - https://imgur.com/a/xNK8URF
индексы были типа str поэтому в float перевел, думал на это ругается

Comment: @CrazyElf https://imgur.com/a/CyDq0u4 . Спасибо,что откликнулись

Comment: Ну NA у вас в frameNew нет, так что дело по крайней мере не в этом. А так по идее seaborn вроде умеет и строковые данные вполне рисовать, мне казалось. Мне странно, что часы в индекс по заданию надо положить. Я бы index ещё на na проверил: frameNew.index.isna().sum()  Ну и параметры sns.heatmap бы посмотреть - умеет ли он обрабатывать строковые данные и что он делает с индексом

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё указать в какой конкретно строке ошибка выходит

Comment: Вот это ещё почитайте. Возможно, со строковыми данными надо что-то сделать, но может это про старую версию Seaborn, не знаю https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227475/heatmap-like-plot-but-for-categorical-variables-in-seaborn